# tolerance interval, sample size and power

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, sample-size, tolerance-interval

I can only find limited information on how to calculate sample sizes in respect to tolerance intervals. I have a particular problem I would appreciate any help on.

If I had a normally distributed random variable with estimated mean = 0 and std = 1 and wanted to take a sample and construct a 90% proportion, 95% confidence tolerance interval such that they was an 0.8 probability that the tolerance was bounded by +/- 2 how would I go about calculating a sample size?

Thanks for any guidance.